# Updating duplicate records so they are filtered

Tags: sql-server

I've found that our website to ERP integration tool will duplicate inserts if there is an error during the sync.  Until the error is resolved, the records will duplicate every time the sync retries, which is usually every 5 minutes.

Trying to find an effective way to update duplicate records so that when queried for a view that the duplicates are filtered.  The challenge I am having is that a duplicate will have some columns that are different.

For example, looking at the SalaesOrderDetail table, an order had 120 line items.  However, because of a sync issue, each line was duplicated.

I've tried using the following to test for the past month:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT  SOHD.[salesorderno], [itemcode],[CommentText], unitofmeasure, itemcodedesc, quantityorderedoriginal, quantityshipped,
 row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY SOHD.[salesorderno], [itemcode], unitofmeasure, itemcodedesc, quantityorderedoriginal, quantityshipped ORDER BY SOHD.[Linekey] desc) AS [rn]
FROM [dbo].[SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail] SOHD
inner join [dbo].[SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader] SOHH on SOHH.Salesorderno = SOHD.Salesorderno
Where year(orderdate) = '2016'
and month(orderdate) = '08'
--Only Look at completed orders, ignore quotes & deleted orders
and SOHH.Orderstatus in ('C')
--Only looks for item lines where something did not ship (prevent removing a "good" entry)
and [quantityshipped] = '0'
)
Select *
from cte
```

However, I keep finding issues with using this because if I were to run an update command with this, it will update some records it shouldn't.  And if I add some of the columns for it to be more specific, it wouldn't edit some columns that it needs to.

For example, if I don't add

```
where rn >1 then I inadvertently edit records that are not duplicates
```

but if I add

```
where rn >1 then the 1st set of duplicate records won't be updated.
```

Feeling stuck, but not sure what to do.

Adding more info from comment section.  I think maybe my cte statement to find the duplicates and an update command might have to be somewhat different.  Example Data:

```
Order#   Itemcode   CommentText   UnitofMeasure   itemcodedesc   qtyordered   qtyshipped
12345     abc        null           each           candy            5            0
12345     abc        null           each           candy            5            5
12345     xyz        null           case           slinky           25            0
12345     xyz        null           case           slinky           25            25
```

So they are not duplicates if I include the qtyshipped column, but what I want to do is update only the records where the qtyshipped = 0.  The update I plan to so is set commenttext = 'delete'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ROW_NUMBER` to `COUNT() Over()` window function

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT SOHD.[salesorderno], 
                [itemcode], 
                [commenttext], 
                unitofmeasure, 
                itemcodedesc, 
                quantityorderedoriginal, 
                quantityshipped, 
                Count(1) 
                  OVER(partition BY SOHD.[salesorderno], [itemcode], unitofmeasure,itemcodedesc) AS [rn] 
         FROM   [dbo].[so_salesorderhistorydetail] SOHD
         ..........) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn > 1
```

Comment: So after doing that, on my order where I have 240 lines (120 are duplicates) I only get 2 results.

Comment: @MattC - Then your `partition by` is wrong. What is the combination for finding duplicate

Comment: I guess that's where I'm stuck.   I think I have to reply to my original message to show the output in a meaningful output.

Comment: @MattC - check now

Comment: That got it.  Thank you so much!  saved me so much headache.